# Click the button using Electron and Nightmare

Tags: async-await, electron, nightmare

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });


nightmare
        .goto('http://football-system.jp/fss/pub_taikaigamelist.php?lid=eBVesRz5C54=')
        .wait(1000)
        .click('a[href="javascript:void(0);"]')
        .wait(1000)

        .then()
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
      });
```

That is my code. I want to click the button and get the HTML of the next page. But I want to use Nightmare and Electron. I don't know how to do this. Maybe about the async and form submit and action.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: There are too many results for your click selector. There are several links on that page that match 'a[href="javascript:void(0);"]'

Comment: This is nodejs . And  This selector can find the first match.Because I just want to click one button.But anyone button cant work.

Comment: maybe the problem is  how to handle POST navigation for new windows

Comment: There are a lot of buttons can be matched by your selector. You can upload a snapshot of the web page and denote which exactly button you want to click.

Comment: Worked for me. I just ran as it is.